# A good, recent article on the comparison between Java EE and .NET?

Tags: c#, java, .net, jakarta-ee

I've started looking into a few larger server-app frameworks that would be able to support desktop client interfaces as well as web interfaces, and have really zero'd down on the two obvious ones: J2EE and .NET. From a language standpoint, feature standpoint, portability standpoint, etc...I am pretty comfortable with my understanding of the two products. I'll keep it simple in saying that for the most part, either would fit the need well enough based on my initial analysis.

Where things are a pain though is in finding a good comparison from engineers who have spent a better part of the decade working with one, the other, or both. The undocumented frustrations that youwont get from Sun, Microsoft or a book.

A Google search turns up plenty of results, but most are from 2002-04. Suffice to say, plenty has changed since. J2EE is suposed to have gotten a lot simpler and .NET is supposed to have gotten a lot more feature rich.

Is anyone aware of more current comparisons (in the last two years) that might be worth reading?

Comment: "...have really zero'd down on the two obvious ones..." - just curious, what were your other candidates?  How many were eliminated from your survey?

Comment: Java is totally cross-plataform, your program will always work don't matter if its Windows, Linux, SunOS, iPhone or a toaster. DotNET is a copy of Java with more Windows specific features, what makes it far faster, easier to use, install and publish sinse you're on Windows world. I would never use Java for someting meant to run on Windows, but maybe that's not your case.

Comment: Java does not run on an iPhone, so that's not strictly true.

Comment: @Havenard - I definitely would not say .Net is a Java clone.  .Net has taken influences from Java, but they are definitely different.  I know of at least on of the C# compiler developer's frequents this site, and would definitely challenge your claims.

Comment: I agree with phsr - Java and C# have traded influences back and forth since C# came along.  It might have been a fair comment to apply to C# 1.0, but there's been a lot of progress with both languages since then.  Annotations appeared first in C#.  C# has closures now; Java does not.  C# is not a knock-off of Java.

Comment: Also, with the proliferation on Mono, .Net is becoming more and more cross platform.  It may not have ALL the features of .Net, but it definitely has the core, and is still growing.  Java is cross platform if there is a JVM for your platform.  I dont think Sun has developed a JVM to run on my toaster yet. ;-)

Comment: Lord, the "Pet Shop" web 1.0 demo. I still have nightmares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say 'desktop' before you said 'web', i can assume that the desktop side of this application is more important. .Net has a definite advantage in making desktop apps, Java really doesn't have this as an advantage.

Having said that, i'd just go with whichever your dev team has more experience in.

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen these?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_vs._Java_and_Java_EE

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_the_Java_and_.NET_platforms

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

Answer (score 1):

Java EE has certainly changed a lot.  The biggest changes that you'll want to be aware of are [Spring](http://www.springframework.org) and the new [EJB3](http://java.sun.com/products/ejb/) spec.

Spring is not part of Sun's Java EE standard.  It's the crystalization of Rod Johnson's consulting experience into a framework for POJO development that's gotten a lot of traction.  And, just for reference, there are versions of Spring for both Java and .NET.  Likewise for Hibernate, a popular ORM tool.

EJB3 has taken a great deal from Spring and Hibernate.  You can use EJB3 with Glassfish or JBOSS or WebLogic.

Another idea that you'll want to keep in mind is web services.  These are distributed web components that can work with any client, Java EE or .NET, desktop or browser.  I think their chief benefits are the emphasis on messages and hiding the back end implementation details.  If you write web services, your clients don't have to know or care whether they're written in Java or .NET.

Web services work well with rich Internet clients like Flex and Silverlight.  They can help to keep your options open.

Sorry, I can't speak from personal experience about .NET.

Answer (score -1):

This is a real "apples and oranges" type question.

Generally speaking I'd rather do desktop development in .Net. If I did it in Java I'd probably favour Eclipse SWT or Netbeans RCP over Java Swing.

For serverside programming you can use either. I'm not a huge fan of Windows as a server platform (over Linux) and the Java stack is essentially free, which is particularly useful in terms of start-up costs (Bizspark notwithstanding).

The biggest thing about Java server apps isn't really J2EE anymore. It's Spring. You'll probably find more Java web apps running with Tomcat and Spring than you do full J2EE stack apps (generally meaning including EJB).

EJB3 has gone POJO like Spring is.